# Disable csrf token for a single form

Tags: django, csrf

I have a html form that send a post data to a django web app from another location. How can i disable the csrf token check for that specific form or request?

Answer (score 6):

You could add the `csrf_exempt` decorator to your view.

#### Example

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

Comment: Not for a view, just a single form. Is a wizard form (crispyform) and i want disable only for the first of them

Comment: You should update your question and include code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned Crispyform in your comment. If you're using the FormHelper function then the solution there is to change to set the disable_csrf attribute.

```
class ExampleForm(forms.Form):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExampleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.disable_csrf = True
```

See here for more info: http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html

Also have a look at their test.py file if this gives you any trouble: http://pydoc.net/Python/django-crispy-forms/1.3.0/crispy_forms.tests.tests/

Specifically:

```
def test_disable_csrf(self):
    form = TestForm()
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.disable_csrf = True
    html = render_crispy_form(form, helper, {'csrf_token': _get_new_csrf_key()})
    self.assertFalse('csrf' in html)
```